# Crystal report sub-report links

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

I am trying to pass a parameter from the main report to a sub-report. I know this can be done from 'change sub-report links', but I assume it only works if the data type are the same for these parameters. Can I still do it if the parameters are of different types? i.e. the main report parameter is of type 'datetime' and sub-report is of type 'string'(which is in fact a string representing datetime). The sub-report calls a store procedure in the DB, which easier to deal with if the parameter is of type string.

I tried create a 'stepping variable'(say call it 'datetimeString') on the main report, to format the datetime parameter into string, then link this 'datetimeString' to the string parameter in the sub-report.

The above does not give me errors when configuring, but the funny thing is that now when i try to preview the main report, the sub-report does not show any data, store procedure in the sub-report is not executed. In the same preview session(without updating the parameters passed in), if i double click on the sub-report to view detail on the sub-report itself, the sub-report opens with data and the store procedure within the sub-report gets call.

It seems like the sub-report is not invoked if its parameter is not linked straight from a main report parameter.

Please let me know if you could suggest anything else to try. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is the stored procedure. Is it treating the input string as a datetime? If so, it should be passed a datetime.

Comment: I had a little problem adding the store procedure to the subreport when the parameter is of type datetime on version 8.5. I am not sure why...by upgrading the report to be version 11 and creating the SP as you suggested worked. the report works now. Thanks.